# Set capybara default_wait_time to a function

Tags: ruby, cucumber, gopro

I made a function called wait_for_page load, and I am trying to set the default_wait_time to this function.

I get an undefined variable error:

> undefined local variable or method `page' for main:Object (NameError)

I also included the file into the main environment file:

> require File.expand_path('../../support/file_name.rb', **FILE**)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`default_wait_time` is an accessor in Capybara module. So you'll need to call it on the Capybara object itself, like:

```
Capybara.default_wait_time = some_value
```

And Capybara object should be available wherever you have defined this method.

In some newer versions accessor is `default_max_wait_time`, you can notice this because of a [DEPRECATION warning](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/teamcapybara/capybara/Capybara#default_wait_time-class_method)
So you need to do this:

```
Capybara.default_max_wait_time = 5
```

The [default](https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara/tree/2.5_stable#asynchronous-javascript-ajax-and-friends) is 2 seconds

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Looks like what i had in mind wont work for this.

Comment: capybara (2.10.1) : #default_wait_time is deprecated, please use #default_max_wait_time instead

Comment: where do you put this

Comment: @BlaineLafreniere : Typically in your setup, where you set Capybara settings like driver and app host (in env file or hooks etc)